# How can I add a subview under statusbar and on top of Navigationbar in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar, subview, uiwindow

I am trying to add a subview in between statusbar and navigationbar, so I have set the y position = 0 and after that I am reducing UIApplication Keywindow size so that it would free up space on top.

but the status bar is looking odd and it has been shifted too.
[image]

The navigationbar is shifted downwards, that's okay. but I need to show proper statusbar also.
Here is my code.

````
    float yPosition = 0;
    CGRect fr = CGRectMake(0, yPosition, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, 40);
    
    runningCallView.frame = fr;
    
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height-40);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view addSubview:runningCallView];```

Can anyone please help on this. Thank you.
````

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.
Now instead of shifting keyWindow downwards, I've shifted down the rootviewController.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, shiftDownwards, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height-shiftDownwards);
```

and added a statusbar subView to show a fake subview on top.
Also UiWindow needed to be subclasses to detect touch on the extra addedView.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```